# A function f with Neuman boundary conditions,C^2 in the clousure domain implies that f is harmonic?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

I want to know if the next conjeture is true or false, I do a proof but I don't know if it is correct.

### Lema

Let be $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ a Domain, $c\in C^2(\overline{\Omega}\times [0,T))$ such that $\partial_{\nu}c=0$ in $\partial \Omega\times (0,T)$, then $c$ is Harmonic.

---

### Proof

Fix $T_0\in (0,T)$ arbitrary and note that for all $t\in (0, T_0)$ we have that $c(\cdot,t)\in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$, using the Green's formulas we have that
\begin{equation*}
0\leq \int_{\Omega} |\Delta c(\cdot, t)|=\pm \int_{\partial\Omega}{\partial_{\nu}c(\cdot, t)}dS=0,
\end{equation*}
then in $(0,T_0)$ we have that $\Delta c=0$ almost everywhere, and using the fact that $c$ is $C^2$, we can state that $\Delta c =0$, and because $T_0$ is arbitrary we can conclude the result.

Comment: Not true, check your proof or better yet discover counterexamples.

Comment: It does not hold in general that $\int_{\Omega}|\Delta c| = \pm\int_{\partial \Omega} \nabla c \cdot n$.